# Multiple mp3 download links to a zip file for download javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, download, zip

So I have this url: https://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=trShzDCP0ESQ5bFdcMpe8y6H6WJvxYLXMa7OtmJMeO%2FqhE5HNe6etvXNYLqsXm5HkScdBuZ%2BJgrHtb%2FWohCaWg%3D%3D

upon clicking it, a download for an mp3 file will start. What I want to do is have multiple of these links and when a user clicks a button, a zip file will be downloaded that contains the downloads from each of the urls.

I was thinking maybe I have to use ajax to click the links and manually store the downloads somewhere before sending to the users downloads directory then use jszip to merge the downloads to a zip and send that zip to be downloaded by the user but I have no clue how to begin or how to do this.

An alternative was to have an array of all the download links and when the button is pressed then each download link is automatically clicked but then the downloads are separate files not 1 zip file.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [this example](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples/downloader.html) as starting point.

The biggest challenge doing that in a browser is [CORS headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing): the remote server **must** allow you (your domain or `*`) to do the request. From what I can see, youtubeinmp3.com doesn't add CORS headers in the respose (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`).

Comment: Ok but doesnt Jszip only allow files to be added to a zip that you already have in your directory? I'm trying to add files to a zip from a download link. Also for the access control allow origin, cant you download the chrome extension to allow it?

Comment: JSZip uses the content you give. If you have an url, you need to fetch its content first. If you have a local file, you need an `<input type="file">` to get the content. We can't really help you more without your code, ideally a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: how would I fetch its content without sending the file to the users download folder